# ggplot: How to draw contour line for 2d scatter plot to outline the data points

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I need to draw a line around all of my data points that plot within x-y space. I do not need 2d density distribution. See the picture attached (the field was just drawn manually). Thank you.
[scatter plot with line around data points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sL1TF.jpg)

Comment: There is a convexhull function is some package or another. But as it's name implies it will be convex. After `sos::findFn("convexhull")` I'd try either `spatstat` or `dismo`. It appears from the illustration of `ggalt::geom_encircle` below, that it might also be a convex result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the perfect use case for `ggalt`'s `geom_encircle`:

```
#install.packages('ggalt')
library(ggalt)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_encircle()
```

[image]

You can also encircle by group:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_encircle()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Looks helpful, however I get the error: could not find function "geom_encircle". I have ggplot2 and ggalt installed. Weird.

Comment: also updated and loaded? On my system: `packageVersion('ggplot2'): ‘2.2.1’`
 `packageVersion('ggalt'): ‘0.4.0’`

Comment: `remove.packages("ggalt")
install.packages("ggalt")
update.packages("ggalt")
packageVersion("ggalt")` gives [1] ‘0.1.1’

Comment: 'ggalt' on [CRAN is at version 0.4.0](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggalt/)

Comment: It requires `ggplot2` version 2.2.1. Is ggplot updated too?

Comment: `remove.packages('ggplot2')
install.packages('ggplot2')
packageVersion('ggplot2')` gives me ‘2.1.0’. I noticed that line `update.packages('ggplot2')` does not do anything. I think that's where the problem is. Thanks for guiding me through this.

Comment: I had to install ggplot2 source package downloaded from CRAN. `install.packages('ggplot2')` would only install older, binary version. Hope it helps to all confused people like me. Thank you again.

Comment: If you decide this answer is helpful, [pls consider accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)